# I'm getting an error when trying to run my HelloWorld program on IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The following code is what I was trying to run

````
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
} ```


Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true "-Dpreload.project.path=C:/Users/Mujahid Jaffer/IdeaProjects/Java Practice" "-Dpreload.config.path=C:/Users/Mujahid Jaffer/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/config/options" -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-3779026609959447050 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2019.2 "-Didea.home.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3" "-Didea.config.path=C:\Users\Mujahid Jaffer/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/config" "-Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users\Mujahid Jaffer/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/config/plugins" "-Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/Mujahid Jaffer/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/system/log/build-log" "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/jbr" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.4 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true "-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/Mujahid Jaffer/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/system/compile-server/java_practice_fbb86c3a/_temp_" -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\MUJAHI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-16623023266407957228-is-running\" -classpath "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-10.0.2/lib/tools.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/netty-transport-4.1.38.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/asm-all-7.0.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-transport-file-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/httpcore-4.4.11.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/guava-25.1-jre.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-util-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-impl-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-builder-support-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/trove4j.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-spi-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-api-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/jdom.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/log4j.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/netty-resolver-4.1.38.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/jna-platform.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-model-builder-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-transport-http-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/lz4-java-1.6.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/netty-common-4.1.38.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/netty-buffer-4.1.38.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/forms-1.1-preview.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-model-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/netty-codec-4.1.38.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/platform-api.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/httpclient-4.5.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-connector-basic-1.1.0.jar;;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jasper-v2-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/guava-25.1-jre.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/common-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-5.2.1-sp1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/lib/guava-25.1-jre.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/common-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-5.2.1-sp1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/osmorc/lib/osmorc-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/osmorc/lib/biz.aQute.bndlib-4.2.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/osmorc/lib/biz.aQute.repository-4.2.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/osmorc/lib/biz.aQute.resolve-4.2.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/osmorc/lib/bundlor-all.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/aspectj/lib/aspectj-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/JavaEE/lib/javaee-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jps/jpa-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/webSphereIntegration/lib/jps/webSphere-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/weblogicIntegration/lib/jps/weblogic-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/build-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/android-extensions-ide.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common-26.3.0-sp1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/common-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/repository-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/sdklib-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api-26.3.0-sp1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger-26.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/flex/lib/flex-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/flex/lib/flex-shared.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/dmServer/lib/dmServer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/GwtStudio/lib/gwt-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/google-app-engine-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/appEngine-runtime.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-compiler-patch.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 50748 0e7c121e-956d-4b6a-8249-18d00e5e6408 "C:/Users/Mujahid Jaffer/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/system/compile-server"
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006f251958, pid=19948, tid=7000
#
# JRE version:  (10.0.2+13) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0.2+13, mixed mode, aot, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x1c1958]#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Mujahid Jaffer\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\compile-server\hs_err_pid19948.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
````

Comment: Try using a more recent Java SDK for the project, like 11.0.4 or 12/13. More details are available in `C:\Users\Mujahid Jaffer\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\compile-server\hs_err_pid19948.log`. It's either a bug in the JDK or some hardware/system issue like a faulty RAM or driver. Antivirus/security tools may also cause such problems.

Comment: Does ```C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe <YourClass>``` work? Eliminate IntelliJ from the problem statement. There seems to be an issue with the JRE that you are using.